# Bounded Laplacian

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, laplacian

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and fix a point $p_0 \in M$. Denote by $d : M \to [0, \infty)$ the "distance to $p_0$" function. It is well known that $d$ is not smooth at $p_0$. Can we say that $\Delta d$, the laplacian of $d$, is bounded in a punctured neighborhood of $p_0$ in $M$? I guess it is not bounded, but I can't prove this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it immediate from the formula for Laplacian in a normal ball?

We have
$$
\Delta_g = -\partial_r^2+\left(\frac{n-1}{r}+\frac{\partial_r J}{J}\right)\partial_r+\Delta_{S_g^{n-1}(r)}
$$
where $J=\det(d\exp_p)$.  Hitting this on $r$, we get
$$
\Delta_g r=-\frac{n-1}{r}-\frac{\partial_r J}{J}
$$
But $J\to 1$ as $r\downarrow 0$ so there is no chance of cancelling the $(n-1)/r$ terms on the right.